# $compile vs $componentController

Tags: angularjs, testing, angularjs-directive

I'm relatively new to Angular and have begun writing my application with a component architecture. When looking through the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) it recommends testing components with the `$componentController` mock method.

However, when I look at how directives have traditionally been tested in Angular pre-1.5 it looks like the preferred method was to use the `$compile` service to actually build your directive template-and-all. By using `$compile` you can make assertions about your template logic as well as the controller logic. Whereas with the `$componentController` method you can only test the controller logic, which doesn't actually seem all that useful since most complexity is found in templates and services.

Can someone shed some light on modern best practices? To me it makes more sense to use `$compile` so that you can test the template as well. But why do the Angular docs not mention this at all and instead recommend `$componentController`?

Comment: Answering w/a comment, b/c it might be more of an opinion. I think you've hit the nail on the head w/your conclusions about the differences between the two. Prior to the introduction of components, they said use directives (and hence use $compile in tests) to do DOM manipulation. That is still the case, I think even w/components. If you need to test that the DOM was manipulated correctly, you need use a directive and $compile. I tend to mostly create components now, and rarely bother w/the DOM level tests b/c it can be cumbersome and it's generally not mission critical logic.

Comment: Unless you plan on migrating from AngularJS to Angular (yes, they are different), you should not tag `angular` (especially since I don't see any references in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/search/#stq=%24componentController&stp=1) about $componentController.

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44165119/2545680) help? anything unclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the biggest problems with AngularJS is that it has `$scope`. This is the place you put your bindings onto that are used in the DOM. It introduced much confusion.

Every good application design should have layers: business logic, UI etc. In AngularJS those layers pretty much corresponded to `controller` for business logic and `directives` for UI. However, because of the `$scope` being available in `directives`, many people decided to not use controllers and put all business logic in directives. This led to hard-to-test directives because they simultaneously implemented both layers. Also test became slow since DOM manipulation is slow.

Ideally, you should put as much testing as possible into business logic and less in the UI. Since framework handles synchronization between business logic and UI there is little possibility of bugs there. But business logic is where most bugs are introduced. That's why in the newer AngularJS they recommend to use `$componentController` to test business logic in controllers, not directives.

New Angular doesn't have `$compile` and most tests are written for controllers, which are implemented as classes there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see a lot of people repeating your sentiment that there is "little possibility of bugs" in the UI. But to me that doesn't seem true. I _am_ using Angular built-in directives in the UI that obviously don't need to be tested on their own, but isn't the conjunction of those directives with my own template and controller something that is worth testing?

Comment: @benjyblack, IMHO, it may require some testing for custom directives that perform tricky DOM manipulations, but otherwise most of the tests should target business logic  in controllers.